# DNS headers are being sent as Raw data with scapy

Tags: python, sockets, dns, scapy

I am trying to set up a socket server on a linux machine using python , as a side project for my networking team.
the machine will listen to port 53, and will respond to dns queries using scapy.

Now, the asking part is all working great, atleast i think, i didnt really get to the part when i set the server as my dns server and try to use the internet yet, but when i try tcpdump it looks like a normal packet.

Anyway, when i respond from the server to the client, the packet is being sent with all the headers that i need, of DNS,DNSQR and DNSRR, as i saw in tcpdump.
But, when the client receive the packet, it only has IP,and UDP headers, as the rest is being sent as Raw data.

As i previously mentioned, i tried looking at wireshark and tcpdump and saw the difference that is being sent between the server and the client, and i saw that from the server side, the reply packet is being marked as  `malformed packet`

Im not completely sure if this is the case, as i saw on the internet that its just because i didnt spoof it complettly.

code:

Client packet:

```
pkt = IP(dst='<Server IP>')/UDP(dport=53,sport=RandShort())/DNS(rd=1,qd=DNSQR(qname='dns.google'))
```

Server packet:

```
def build_dns_response(src_addr,og_sport,dns_qtype,dns_qname,response_type=True,response_name=None):
    '''
    a function that will build a DNS response packet back to the sender, according to the parameters that are recieved.
    dns_qname = url/ip that the sender asked for.
    og_sport = original source port, will be used as the dport of this packet
    src_addr = source address of the original packet, will be used as the destination of this packet.
    dns_qtype = the question type of the original request, 1 stands for type A, and 12 for PTR
    response_type = will indicate if the server responds with an answer of 'ok' or 'name-error' on the 'rcode' field,True for ok,False for name-error
    response_name = the response that the server will send as a result of the dns request, in case that a request matches to a database query.
    '''
    if response_type is True:
        pkt = IP(src='<Server IP>',dst=src_addr)/\
                                UDP(sport=53,dport=og_sport)/\
                                DNS(opcode=0,rd=1,rcode='ok',nscount=1,ancount=1,qd=DNSQR(qname=dns_qname,qtype=dns_qtype),an=DNSRR(rrname=dns_qname,type=dns_qtype,rdata=response_name))
```

packet being sent by server:

```
###[ IP ]### 
  version   = 4
  ihl       = None
  tos       = 0x0
  len       = None
  id        = 1
  flags     = 
  frag      = 0
  ttl       = 64
  proto     = udp
  chksum    = None
  src       = <Server IP>
  dst       = <client IP >
  \options   \
###[ UDP ]### 
     sport     = domain
     dport     = 25151
     len       = None
     chksum    = None
###[ DNS ]### 
        id        = 0
        qr        = 0
        opcode    = QUERY
        aa        = 0
        tc        = 0
        rd        = 1
        ra        = 0
        z         = 0
        ad        = 0
        cd        = 0
        rcode     = ok
        qdcount   = 1
        ancount   = 1
        nscount   = 1
        arcount   = 0
        \qd        \
         |###[ DNS Question Record ]### 
         |  qname     = 'dns.google.'
         |  qtype     = A
         |  qclass    = IN
        \an        \
         |###[ DNS Resource Record ]### 
         |  rrname    = 'dns.google.'
         |  type      = A
         |  rclass    = IN
         |  ttl       = 0
         |  rdlen     = None
         |  rdata     = 8.8.8.8
        ns        = None
        ar        = None
```

packet that is received by the client:

```
###[ IP ]###
  version   = 4
  ihl       = 5
  tos       = 0x0
  len       = 82
  id        = 1
  flags     =
  frag      = 0
  ttl       = 64
  proto     = udp
  chksum    = 0x6686
  src       = <Server IP>
  dst       = <Client IP>
  \options   \
###[ UDP ]###
     sport     = domain
     dport     = 25151
     len       = 62
     chksum    = 0xf99
###[ Raw ]###
        load      = '\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x01\x00\x01\x00\x01\x00\x00\x03dns\x06google\x00\x00\x01\x00\x01\x03dns\x06google\x00\x00\x01\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x04\x08\x08\x08\x08'
```

I guess its worth mentioning that the entire conversation is from Host PC to vm being hosted on it.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Can you provide the output for `raw(packet)` for both packets next to your `packet.show()`?

Comment: You have cropped too much info. How do you send any of the packets ? Do you use level 2 or 3 sockets ? Malformed packet could be the checksum, a failed length field or a more general issue with packet building. Make sure Scapy calculates checksums & lengths, make sure they are correctly calculated. Did you try to use `DNS_am` from scapy's source code or take inspiration from it ? Look it up, it's an answering machine for DNS